# D3 js to react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, linechart

How do I convert the below javascript line chart code to React line graph Component ?

[line with brush](http://bl.ocks.org/Nympheo/65db03c2d8f0b8aea962f95b1bff6489)

the above link is **D3js** which is line chart. I need to covert it to my class component.
how to handle the D3 svg in reactjs

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll get more useful answers if you show some of the code you've attempted and tell us how it has or hasn't worked for you.

Comment: In general, React components are like functional containers for code, so you could easily wrap your existing JS, CSS, and HTML code in a component. However, you should do some research to see if there is a semantic/framework-specific wrapper for D3, so that your component works well with any other D3 code in your site or webapp, and is easy to use and re-use.